# Proof of non-trivial fact to show singularity is essential

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, singularity

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100117/show-that-a-function-has-essential-singularity) the asker wanted to show that the function
$$f:z\mapsto\frac{(e^{iz}-1)e^{1/z}}{\sin z}$$
Has an essential singularity at $0$. User [@wisefool](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/51807/wisefool) came up with two complex sequences $z_n=1/n$ and $w_n=i/n$ that both converge to $0$, and showed that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(z_n)|\neq \lim_{n\to\infty}|f(w_n)|$$
And used this to conclude the singularity at $0$ is essential. My question is... **why**? This really doesn't seem obvious to me, and he neither gave nor linked to any proof. Could someone help me construct a proof for this?

Comment: for an isolated singularity, poles have unique limit (infinity) and removable singularities have a unique finite limit (whatever value gets to be), so only essential singularities can have two distinct limits

Comment: @Conrad Okay, but do you have proof?

Comment: what do you mean? by definition of a pole of order $n \ge 1$ we have $f(z)=g(z)/(z-w)^n$ with $g$ analytic near $w$ and $g(w) \ne 0$ so obviously $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to w$ since $1/|z-w|^n$ does so while $g(w) \ne 0$ is finite; for removable singularity $f$ extends analytically hence continuously to $w$ so $|f(z)| \to |f(w)|$ finite fixed

Comment: @Conrad That makes sense. If you could expand your comment into a full answer I would accept it and it would mark this query as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ an analytic function with an isolated singularity at $w$

By definition of a pole of order $n \ge 1$, we have $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-w)^n}$ for $z$ in a small neighborhood of $w$ where $g$ is analytic there and $g(w) \ne 0$, This clearly implies that $|f(w)| \to \infty, z \to w$ as $1/|z-w|^n$ does so while $g(w) \ne 0$

By definition of a removable singularity, $f$ extends analytically hence continuously to $w$ so $f(z) \to f(w)$ which implies $|f(z)| \to |f(w)|, z \to w$

So in both cases above we get a unique limit, infinity for poles, and arbitrary finite for removable singularities.

The only case where two distinct limits are possible is when the singularity is essential

Comment: Straightforward. Thanks for pointing out the gap in my thinking.

Comment: happy to be of help